# Powershell foreach script keep looping

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get list of VLFs using dbatools and prepare this script and it gave me the result I want but it never stops, keep running

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\test\server_lists_agents.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
   Test-DbaDbVirtualLogFile -SqlInstance $servers | select sqlinstance, database, total 
}

$servers = Get-Content "C:\test\server_lists_agents.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
   Test-DbaDbVirtualLogFile -SqlInstance $servers | select sqlinstance, database, total 
}
```

Comment: you have used the collection variable `$servers` where you need to use the _item_ variable `$server`. [*grin*] ///// this is a **_classic_** example about why the name of the collection and the current item need to be VIVIDLY different. use something like `foreach $S_Item in $Servers)` or `foreach ($SL_Item in $ServerList)`.

Comment: Alternatively, `$servers | % {Test-DbaDbVirtualLogFile -SqlInstance $_}`